# Why is Apache POI able to write a hyperlink more than 255 characters but not XLSXWriter?

Tags: java, python, excel, apache-poi, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to embed a bunch of URLs into an Excel file using Python with XLSXWriter's function write_url(), but it gives me the warning of it exceeding the 255 character limit. I think this is happening because it may be using the built-in HYPERLINK Excel function.

However, I found that Apache POI from Java doesn't seem to have that issue. Is it because they directly write it into the cell itself or is there a different reason? Also, is there a workaround in Python that can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the length limitation of a hyperlink address in .xlsx (using Excel 2013) is 2084 characters. Generating a file with a longer address using POI, repairing it with Excel and saving it will yield an address with a length of 2084 characters.

The Excel UI and .xls files seem to have a limit of 255 characters, as already mentioned by other commenters.

Answer (score 0):

255 characters in a URL is an Excel 2007+ limitation. Try it in Excel.

I think the XLS format allowed longer URLs (so perhaps that is the difference).

Also XlsxWriter doesn't use the HYPERLINK() function internally (although it is available to the user via the standard interface).

Comment: I tried in Excel 2013 with an XLSX file and it worked fine with no problems.

Comment: Are you sure? I tried to create a URL longer than 255 characters in Excel 2013 and it doesn't work. Try the following. 1, Create a 255 character URL in Excel 2013 in A1. 2. Use LEN(A1) to check. 3. Mouse-over or click the link to verify that it is a link. 4. Copy and paste these cells to new cells. 5. Add one extra character to the URL. 6. Notice that it still looks like a link but you cannot click on it, the mouseover isn't a link, and if you edit it the address field is empty.

Comment: Also, a google search for [max url length in excel](https://www.google.com/#q=max+url+length+in+excel) shows lots of complaints about the 255 character limitation.

Comment: What I did was [this](http://i.imgur.com/4c3H2sk.png) but when I copied it to another cell, and added an extra character to the end of the URL, and clicked OK, and then hovered over the URL, Excel completely ignored the change.

Comment: @silver2049 So you agree that Excel 2007+ doesn't support URLs greater than 255 characters?

Comment: Just to avoid any confusion, when I said Excel completely ignored the change, I meant that the URL never changed but the hyperlink was still available even when it surpassed 255 characters. I am able to hyperlink links more than 350 characters using the Apache POI library in Java.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84489/discussion-between-jmcnamara-and-silver2049).